# How can I unit test a goroutine that runs on an infinite for loop using sync.Cond?

Tags: go, synchronization, mutex

I am trying to unit test a channel that runs on an infinite for loop. I think I've found a way to do it, but I'm not sure if it's a valid way to use conditional variables. Also I'm not sure if this approach is prone to a race condition. Since the for loop is running on its own goroutine, is it possible the channel would be drained by the time I get to "cond.Wait()?" If this happened would I hang forever? In all the examples I've seen using conditional variables they are usually accompanied by a for loop surrounding the wait. Do I need this here? My question: is there anything wrong with the approach I'm using here? Is this a valid/idiomatic use of conditional variables?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var doStuffChan chan bool
var cond *sync.Cond
var result string

func main() {
    doStuffChan = make(chan bool, 10)
    cond = &sync.Cond{L: &sync.Mutex{}}
    go startDoStuffLoop()

    doStuffChan <- true

    cond.L.Lock()
    cond.Wait()
    cond.L.Unlock()

    fmt.Println(result)
}

func startDoStuffLoop() {
    for {
        <-doStuffChan
        result = "success"
        cond.Broadcast()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind you are right in all of your assumptions. To avoid channel draining just use

```
close(doStuffChan)
```

instead of `doStuffChan <- true`, because you can receive nil from closed channel forever.
Them surround Wait with loop to check before cond been true since it's a condition in most cases. If you don't want to close channel guard signalling in channel and broadcasting with Lock, which make operation precedence deterministic.

```
func main() {
    doStuffChan = make(chan bool)
    cond = &sync.Cond{L: &sync.Mutex{}}
    go startDoStuffLoop()

    cond.L.Lock()
    doStuffChan <- true
    cond.Wait()
    cond.L.Unlock()

    fmt.Println(result)
}

func startDoStuffLoop() {
    for {
        <-doStuffChan
        result = "success"
        cond.L.Lock()
        cond.Broadcast()
        cond.L.Unlock()
    }
}
```

See it works https://play.golang.org/p/1S6VW7nIoV  Both versions are threadsafe however.

Comment: If I close the doStuffChan it doesn't work anymore. Also, I need to keep the channel open to receive future events. Basically I need a way to check if one iteration of the doStuffLoop ran. But the channel should remain open for future operations. https://play.golang.org/p/gsOwifVkOZ

Comment: Also I'm still not sure whether or not it's possible to hit a race condition here.

Comment: Could you explain why we need to place "cond.L.Lock()" before "doStuffChan <- true"? And why surrounding "cond.Broadcast()" with a lock makes operation precedence deterministic? I don't really understand how the mutex locks in variable conditions work.

Comment: We Lock in main, then we communicate channel, then startDoStaffLoop goroutine blocks on cond.L.Lock() before main.cond.Wait() unlock mutex and only then routine can  Broadcast. Guaranteed to be exactly in this order.